# Accessing _local memory gives CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I need calculate sum of pair of work item's variable. For my use-case, group size is {8} and I need to calculate sum of work item pairs [0,1], [2,3], [4,5], [6,7]. I do this sum in local function which is called by kernel function.

**partial code:**

```
__local float localSum[8];
int lid = get_local_id(0);
localSum[lid] = var;
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
if (lid % 2 == 0) {
   localSum[lid] += localSum[lid+1];
   // localSum[lid] = 0.f; //Incorrect implementation but works
}
```

With above code after enqueuing kernel, it gives CL_INVALID_PROGRAM_EXECUTABLE. I tried debugging using clGetProgramBuildInfo to make sure compilation of kernel was ok. And, I don't see any error message, just couple of warnings about unused variables.

If I comment pair sum line and uncomment line below (which is not I want functionally), it doesn't give any error.

Is there anything wrong with this code? My only guess is I shouldn't do this in local function. Are there any restrictions on what can't be done in local function versus kernel code?

Comment: I just tried my guess. And it works. I declare __local float localSum[8] in kernel function and then pass that pointer and thread-id returned by get_local_id. But, question remains, what are the restriction on what can be done in local function?

Comment: What are your local and global work group sizes?

Comment: local size is {8}.
global size is { h * localSize[0]}. Here is h is dynamic depending upon the workload size.

Answer (score 0):

On the device side, memory in the *__local* address space can only be allocated within kernel functions, not any other device functions that you call from there. Relevant excerpt from the [OpenCL Reference](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenCL/sdk/2.1/docs/man/xhtml/local.html):

> Pointers to the __local address space are allowed as arguments to
>   functions (including kernel functions). Variables allocated in the
>   __local address space inside a kernel function must occur at kernel function scope.

You can, however, allocate the variable in your kernel function and then pass a pointer. Example:

```c
kernel void test() {
    __local float localSum[8];
    calculate(localSum);
}

void calculate(__local float *localSum) {
    size_t lid = get_local_id(0);
    localSum[lid] = 0;
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    if (lid % 2 == 0) {
       localSum[lid] += localSum[lid+1];
       localSum[lid] = 0.f; //Incorrect implementation but works
    }
}
```